# Editing Create-React-App ESLint rules

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I've installed and imported some lodash methods in my CRA app like so:

```
import find from 'lodash/find';
```

And I now have dozens of ES lint warnings:
[image]

From what I understand, CRA [deliberately](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/808#issuecomment-286870431) prevents editing these rules. But maybe I'm misunderstanding. How can I go about editing these rules? Must I eject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you installed a library **into the source folder**. So it gets checked.

Move it from `src/node_modules` to top-level `node_modules`. If you have a `package.json` in `src`, delete it and declare dependencies in top-level `package.json`. This should fix the issue.

That said, no, linter is not configurable. But of course what you are describing is not a normal situation, and is just caused by installing a dependency in the source folder.

Comment: Thanks, Dan; silly me. As for the second part of my question, is there a way for me to edit these rules, for example, to stifle the `no-unused-vars` warnings?

Comment: No (we picked a very minimal subset that almost always indicates a bug). But you can ignore individual lines with `// eslint-disable-next-line`, as suggested on the warning screen.